# How to disable 'Your connection is not private' screen in Chrome?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

[image: Your connection is not private message screen]

I'm working on automating a web application (F# and Canopy). Getting 'Your connection is not private' screen upon launching the website/ after providing login credentials. Tried a few workaround to have the same disabled, but none did the job. Please help.

Comment: I have already tried the following in chrome://flags: 1. Enable 'Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.' 2. Enable 'Insecure origins treated as secure'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the following argument and it did the job:

options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors")

Comment: This blocks the website completely

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is not try to hide or cover up the problem, but to fix it properly so you don't have to. Solutions that involve hiding the issue are necessarily going to adversely affect your security.

Note the wording of the error code: `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. That tells us that the certificate for the site is signed by a non-standard or unknown certificate authority.

You mentioned `localhost` in your comment; you're not going to be able to get a certificate for that, but you could create a self-signed one, however, if you've enabled the localhost exemption and you're still getting the error, it suggests that you may not be using localhost after all.

So, if you have a certificate signed by a real CA and you're seeing this error, it's likely that your local OS or browser has an outdated CA root certificate bundle. you can usually get the latest one by making sure your OS packages are up to date.

If your certificate is self-signed, then the 'advanced' button will allow you to add an exemption. I you have set up your own CA and signed the certificate with that, you need to add that CA's public key that signed it to your OS.

If you've got a "regular" commercial certificate from verisign, letsencrypt, comodo or whoever, then a run through a testing tool like [testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh) or [Qualys SSL labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) will tell you more about what's going wrong. Without knowing the actual domain we can't test anything for you.

Comment: If there's a problem I don't want to hide it or cover it up... a self signed certificate is NOT a problem for this site.

Comment: Fine, so do what I suggested and add an exemption for this cert, run your own CA. However there is nothing you can do to prevent public visitors from seeing these problems, because making that possible would undermine the entire point of using TLS.